# When I append something to my array it doesn't add anything to the list

Tags: c#, arrays, list

basically I'm trying to append something to an array, but for some reason in wont even work.

(gObject is a thing with a name and a value)

```
public gObject[] OBJECTS = {};
public void RegisterObjectToRender(gObject reg)
{
    OBJECTS.Append<gObject>(reg);
    for (int ri = 0; ri < OBJECTS.Length; ri++)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(OBJECTS[ri].Name);
    }
}
```

I hope everyone who is reading this is having a good day btw

Comment: tried the debugger to step thru?

Comment: I was in debug mode.

Comment: Never heard of append, but arrray.resize (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=net-6.0) works by passing a reference of the array. Are you positive append doesn’t return a new array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append returns a new IEnumerable. It does not add to the OBJECTS, but essentially returns a new list. You have to capture the result of Append and use that: var extendedList = OBJECTS.Append(reg).

A better way is to use a list and use Add instead of Append. It is faster and cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are fixed size, always. If you want a list: *use a list*, i.e. use `List<Your type>` instead of an array. A list has an `Add` method.

I'm guessing the `Append` method here is a local extension method that only exists in your code (that isn't a normal API). I'm also guessing that it calls `Array.Resize` internally, but: that creates a new and different array - it doesn't change the existing array. So if you use that, you'd need to swap the underlying reference afterwards, too - to the new array reference. However, don't do that: `Array.Resize` is incredibly inefficient, as it allocates a new array every append (contrast `List<T>` which keeps an oversized backing array, and tracks the count separately, only increasing the underlying array occasionally).

Comment: I am guessing `Append` could be the LINQ extension method - so the expression is just returning `IEnumerable` but not modifying at all

Comment: @MartinZikmund oof, indeed; yeah, that could be the case